# WebAPI 2 Returns Empty List of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have this action that is supposed to return a list of students

```
[HttpGet("GetAllStudentsByYear/{year}")]
public IActionResult GetAllStudentsByYear(int year)
{
    using (var db = new StudentsCFD())
    {
        List<student> stud = (from std in db.student 
                              join c in db.cppsas 
                                on std.cppsa_id equals c.cppsa_ID 
                              where c.school_yr == year 
                              select std).ToList();
        return Ok(stud);
    }
}
```

I am one hundred percent certain stud is not `null`, it has 28 objects when debugging. However my output when called looks like this.

```
[
  {}
]
```

Comment: Are you sure there are 28 items in `stud`? What do you get if you temporarily change the method to `return Ok(stud.Count());`?

Comment: Would you get same result if you change action return type to `List<student>` and `return stud;`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, return `Ok(stud.Count())` returned 28

Comment: @Andrei I did this and got the same result `[ { } ]`, but essentially, the entity is a massive object, I wonder if it has to do with maybe their being a circular key reference? Could that be a problem?

Comment: adding `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` before the linq worked. It looks like it was a circular or large referencing of foreign keys.

Comment: Dangers of lazy-loading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` before the linq worked. It looks like it was a circular or large referencing of foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you directly return stud? If yes then try it once.
e.g. `return stud;`
And if return type `IActionResult`gives error make it `dynamic`